# AWS MQ with Magento 2.4 Open Source

Tags: magento2.4.5, message-queue, rabbit-mq, opensource

Is it enough to update the env.php file queue section to setup AWS MQ (Rabbit MQ as the messaging broker - version  3.9.13) Magento 2 version is M2.4.5

1. Setup the cron.
2. I have done the below change in env.php:

> ```
>  'queue' => [
>         'amqp' => [
>             'host' => 'aws-mq-amqp-endpoint',
>             'port' => 5671,
>             'user' => 'user-name',
>             'password' => 'Password',
>             'virtualhost' => '/',
>             'ssl' => false
>         ],
>         'topics' => [
>             'product_action_attribute.update' => [
>                 'publisher' => 'amqp-magento'
>             ],
>             'product_action_attribute.website.update' => [
>                 'publisher' => 'amqp-magento'
>             ],
>             'media.storage.catalog.image.resize' => [
>                 'publisher' => 'amqp-magento'
>             ],
>             'sales_rule.codegenerator' => [
>                 'publisher' => 'amqp-magento'
>             ],
>             'import_export.export' => [
>                 'publisher' => 'amqp-magento'
>             ],
>             'inventory.source.items.cleanup' => [
>                 'publisher' => 'amqp-magento'
>             ],
>             'inventory.mass.update' => [
>                 'publisher' => 'amqp-magento'
>             ],
>             'inventory.reservations.cleanup' => [
>                 'publisher' => 'amqp-magento'
>             ],
>             'inventory.reservations.update' => [
>                 'publisher' => 'amqp-magento'
>             ],
>             'inventory.reservations.updateSalabilityStatus' => [
>                 'publisher' => 'amqp-magento'
>             ],
>             'inventory.indexer.sourceItem' => [
>                 'publisher' => 'amqp-magento'
>             ],
>             'inventory.indexer.stock' => [
>                 'publisher' => 'amqp-magento'
>             ],
>             'media.content.synchronization' => [
>                 'publisher' => 'amqp-magento'
>             ],
>             'media.gallery.synchronization' => [
>                 'publisher' => 'amqp-magento'
>             ]
>         ],
>         'config' => [
>             'publishers' => [
>                 'product_action_attribute.update' => [
>                     'connections' => [
>                         'amqp' => [
>                             'name' => 'amqp',
>                             'exchange' => 'magento',
>                             'disabled' => false
>                         ],
>                         'db' => [
>                             'name' => 'db',
>                             'exchange' => 'magento',
>                             'disabled' => true
>                         ]
>                     ]
>                 ],
>                 'product_action_attribute.website.update' => [
>                     'connections' => [
>                         'amqp' => [
>                             'name' => 'amqp',
>                             'exchange' => 'magento',
>                             'disabled' => false
>                         ],
>                         'db' => [
>                             'name' => 'db',
>                             'exchange' => 'magento',
>                             'disabled' => true
>                         ]
>                     ]
>                 ],
>                 'media.storage.catalog.image.resize' => [
>                     'connections' => [
>                         'amqp' => [
>                             'name' => 'amqp',
>                             'exchange' => 'magento',
>                             'disabled' => false
>                         ],
>                         'db' => [
>                             'name' => 'db',
>                             'exchange' => 'magento',
>                             'disabled' => true
>                         ]
>                     ]
>                 ],
>                 'sales_rule.codegenerator' => [
>                     'connections' => [
>                         'amqp' => [
>                             'name' => 'amqp',
>                             'exchange' => 'magento',
>                             'disabled' => false
>                         ],
>                         'db' => [
>                             'name' => 'db',
>                             'exchange' => 'magento',
>                             'disabled' => true
>                         ]
>                     ]
>                 ],
>                 'import_export.export' => [
>                     'connections' => [
>                         'amqp' => [
>                             'name' => 'amqp',
>                             'exchange' => 'magento',
>                             'disabled' => false
>                         ],
>                         'db' => [
>                             'name' => 'db',
>                             'exchange' => 'magento',
>                             'disabled' => true
>                         ]
>                     ]
>                 ],
>                 'inventory.source.items.cleanup' => [
>                     'connections' => [
>                         'amqp' => [
>                             'name' => 'amqp',
>                             'exchange' => 'magento',
>                             'disabled' => false
>                         ],
>                         'db' => [
>                             'name' => 'db',
>                             'exchange' => 'magento',
>                             'disabled' => true
>                         ]
>                     ]
>                 ],
>                 'inventory.mass.update' => [
>                     'connections' => [
>                         'amqp' => [
>                             'name' => 'amqp',
>                             'exchange' => 'magento',
>                             'disabled' => false
>                         ],
>                         'db' => [
>                             'name' => 'db',
>                             'exchange' => 'magento',
>                             'disabled' => true
>                         ]
>                     ]
>                 ],
>                 'inventory.reservations.cleanup' => [
>                     'connections' => [
>                         'amqp' => [
>                             'name' => 'amqp',
>                             'exchange' => 'magento',
>                             'disabled' => false
>                         ],
>                         'db' => [
>                             'name' => 'db',
>                             'exchange' => 'magento',
>                             'disabled' => true
>                         ]
>                     ]
>                 ],
>                 'inventory.reservations.update' => [
>                     'connections' => [
>                         'amqp' => [
>                             'name' => 'amqp',
>                             'exchange' => 'magento',
>                             'disabled' => false
>                         ],
>                         'db' => [
>                             'name' => 'db',
>                             'exchange' => 'magento',
>                             'disabled' => true
>                         ]
>                     ]
>                 ],
>                 'inventory.reservations.updateSalabilityStatus' => [
>                     'connections' => [
>                         'amqp' => [
>                             'name' => 'amqp',
>                             'exchange' => 'magento',
>                             'disabled' => false
>                         ],
>                         'db' => [
>                             'name' => 'db',
>                             'exchange' => 'magento',
>                             'disabled' => true
>                         ]
>                     ]
>                 ],
>                 'inventory.indexer.sourceItem' => [
>                     'connections' => [
>                         'amqp' => [
>                             'name' => 'amqp',
>                             'exchange' => 'magento',
>                             'disabled' => false
>                         ],
>                         'db' => [
>                             'name' => 'db',
>                             'exchange' => 'magento',
>                             'disabled' => true
>                         ]
>                     ]
>                 ],
>                 'inventory.indexer.stock' => [
>                     'connections' => [
>                         'amqp' => [
>                             'name' => 'amqp',
>                             'exchange' => 'magento',
>                             'disabled' => false
>                         ],
>                         'db' => [
>                             'name' => 'db',
>                             'exchange' => 'magento',
>                             'disabled' => true
>                         ]
>                     ]
>                 ],
>                 'media.content.synchronization' => [
>                     'connections' => [
>                         'amqp' => [
>                             'name' => 'amqp',
>                             'exchange' => 'magento',
>                             'disabled' => false
>                         ],
>                         'db' => [
>                             'name' => 'db',
>                             'exchange' => 'magento',
>                             'disabled' => true
>                         ]
>                     ]
>                 ],
>                 'media.gallery.synchronization' => [
>                     'connections' => [
>                         'amqp' => [
>                             'name' => 'amqp',
>                             'exchange' => 'magento',
>                             'disabled' => false
>                         ],
>                         'db' => [
>                             'name' => 'db',
>                             'exchange' => 'magento',
>                             'disabled' => true
>                         ]
>                     ]
>                 ]
>             ]
>         ],
>         'consumers' => [
>             'product_action_attribute.update' => [
>                 'connection' => 'amqp'
>             ],
>             'product_action_attribute.website.update' => [
>                 'connection' => 'amqp'
>             ],
>             'media.storage.catalog.image.resize' => [
>                 'connection' => 'amqp'
>             ],
>             'codegeneratorProcessor' => [
>                 'connection' => 'amqp'
>             ],
>             'exportProcessor' => [
>                 'connection' => 'amqp'
>             ],
>             'inventory.source.items.cleanup' => [
>                 'connection' => 'amqp'
>             ],
>             'inventory.mass.update' => [
>                 'connection' => 'amqp'
>             ],
>             'inventory.reservations.cleanup' => [
>                 'connection' => 'amqp'
>             ],
>             'inventory.reservations.update' => [
>                 'connection' => 'amqp'
>             ],
>             'inventory.reservations.updateSalabilityStatus' => [
>                 'connection' => 'amqp'
>             ],
>             'inventory.indexer.sourceItem' => [
>                 'connection' => 'amqp'
>             ],
>             'inventory.indexer.stock' => [
>                 'connection' => 'amqp'
>             ],
>             'media.content.synchronization' => [
>                 'connection' => 'amqp'
>             ],
>             'media.gallery.synchronization' => [
>                 'connection' => 'amqp'
>             ]
>         ]
>     ]
> ```

3. Enable **Stores > Configuration > Catalog > Inventory > Admin bulk operations > Run asynchronously.**
4. Run php bin/magento setup:upgrade command

But when Go to Catalog > Products. From the grid, select the product created above and click Assign Inventory Source.
Click Save & Close to complete the process.

I have got below error in system.log of magento 2

> [2023-01-17T14:16:25.681334+00:00] main.CRITICAL: Invalid frame type
> 21 [] [] [2023-01-17T14:16:25.696506+00:00] main.ERROR: Something went
> wrong while processing the request. [] []

On Admin panel it is showing :
[image]

Answer (score 0):

AWS uses amqps (amqp over ssl), so you must set

```
'ssl' => 'true'
```

in you `env.php`. Also note that `true` is a string and not a boolean (There is a strict comparison for this in the Magento Framework code).